# Explanatory string in a custom exception object

Tags: string, exception, c++14

I have a `.hpp` file that looks as follows:

```
#ifndef ERROR_HPP
#define ERROR_HPP

#include <string>
using std::string;

enum class error_code {BAD_FILE_NAME, BAD_FILE_INPUT, BAD_QUERY, BAD_FILE_OPEN, BAD_CACHE_CAPACITY};

class error{
public:
   error(error_code, string);
   ~error();
public:
   string what () const;
private:
   error_code e;
   string msg;
};


#endif
```

In the corresponding .cpp file, I have the following definitions:

```
#include "error.hpp"

error::error(error_code e, string msg){
   this->e = e;
   this->msg = msg;
}

error::~error(){

}

string error::what () const{
   return msg;
}
```

In another `.hpp` file (using templates), I have the following code segment:

```
ifstream file_handle(filename);
if(!file_handle){
error e (error_code::BAD_FILE_NAME, "Can't open file %s", filename);
throw e;
}
```

For the construction part of the error object, I get the following compilation error (quite understandably):

```
9 error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'error    '
 10       error e (error_code::BAD_FILE_NAME, "Can't open file %s", filename);
 11             ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 12 note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 argumen    ts, but 3 were provided 
 13    error(error_code, string);
 14    ^
```

My question is: how can I construct a string during the construction of the error object, so as to pass the file name as an argument, which would be written to cout?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of function which takes variadic arguments, constructs the formatted string and returns it, and then you can pass the result of that function to your `error` class constructor. For example (this is something I have as a cross platform implementation for the same purpose):

```
static inline std::string FormatStringMessage(const char* pErrorMessage, ...)
{
    std::string sFormattedMessage;
    va_list VariableArgumentList;
    va_start(VariableArgumentList, pErrorMessage);
#if defined(_WIN32)
    const auto nMessageSize = _vscprintf(pErrorMessage, VariableArgumentList) + 1;
    sFormattedMessage.resize(nMessageSize);
    vsnprintf_s(const_cast<char*>(sFormattedMessage.data()), sFormattedMessage.size(), sFormattedMessage.size(), pErrorMessage, VariableArgumentList);
#else
    va_list VariableArgumentListCopy;
    va_copy(VariableArgumentListCopy, VariableArgumentList);
#if defined(__APPLE__)
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-nonliteral"
#endif
    auto nFormattedSize = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, pErrorMessage, VariableArgumentListCopy);
    if (nFormattedSize <= 0)
    {
        va_end(VariableArgumentList);
        va_end(VariableArgumentListCopy);
        return "";
    }
    sFormattedMessage.resize(static_cast<size_t>(nFormattedSize) + 1);
    vsnprintf(const_cast<char*>(sFormattedMessage.data()), sFormattedMessage.size(), pErrorMessage, VariableArgumentList);
#if defined(__APPLE__)
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
#endif
    va_end(VariableArgumentListCopy);
#endif
    va_end(VariableArgumentList);
    return sFormattedMessage;
}
```

With such a function you can then do the following - `error e (error_code::BAD_FILE_NAME, FormatStringMessage("Can't open file %s", filename));`